# How can I overwrite the default content of a bootstrap element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following element from Bootstrap:

```html
<li class="VuePagination__pagination-item page-item  VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-chunk disabled">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" disabled="disabled" class="page-link">&lt;&lt;</a>
</li>
```

I would like to have this inside the link instead:

```
font-family: "Ionicons";
font-weight: bold;
content: "\F3D1";
```

How can I achieve this  with either CSS or JQuery?

Comment: Just put inside the `a` tag a `span` tag, just like in the instructions: https://useiconic.com/guides/how-to-use-the-icon-font/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your CSS

```
.page-item a:after {
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "\F3D1";
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block; /*remove if not needed*/
}
```

That's it.

Comment: thank`s that's exactly what I was loking for, since I can't directly access the HTML because this is compiled as a result of an npm component. Also, how can I get rid of the &lt;&lt; what's now in the anchor tag?

Comment: try something like this `document.querySelector('.page-item a').text = document.querySelector('.page-item a').text.slice(8);` It is better if you can give an ID and change the querySelector with it. So it affects only this anchor (e.g. `document.querySelector('#newID a')`)